# How to add two different magnitudes of point size in a ggplot bubbles chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph-visualization

I just encountered such graph attached where two colors of geom_point are used (I believe it is made by ggplot2). Similarly, I would like to have dots of one color to range from size 1 to 5, and have another color for a series of dots for the range 10 to 50. I have however no clue on how to add two different ranges of point in one graph.

At the basic step I have:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(10,20,30,40,50)
Species <- factor(c("Species1","Species2","Species3","Species4","Species5"))
bubba <- data.frame(Sample1=a,Sample2=b,Species=Species)
bubba$Species=factor(bubba$Species, levels=bubba$Species)
xm=melt(bubba,id.vars = "Species", variable.name="Samples", value.name = "Size")
str(xm)
ggplot(xm,aes(x= Samples,y= fct_rev(Species)))+geom_point(aes(size=Size))+scale_size(range = range(xm$Size))+theme_bw()
```

Any would have clues where I should look into ? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That is, can you add some data so that your code can be run?

Comment: Yes: 'a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(10,20,30,40,50)
Species <- factor(c("Species1","Species2","Species3","Species4","Species5"))
bubba <- data.frame(Sample1=a,Sample2=b,Species=Species)
bubba$Species=factor(bubba$Species, levels=bubba$Species)
xm=melt(bubba,id.vars = "Species", variable.name="Samples", value.name = "Size")
str(xm)
ggplot(xm,aes(x= Samples,y= fct_rev(Species)))+geom_point(aes(size=Size))+scale_size(range = range(xm$Size))+theme_bw()'

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there, so that it is neat & tidy with code tags, etc.

Comment: `ggplot` is designed to prevent this. Separate scales for the same aesthetic, in your case `size`, is not possible, bc it makes for hard to understand visualization

Comment: Hi Nate, I just assumed that the graph was above made from ggplot2 because of its background. But if you have other alternatives than ggplot2 I would also appreciate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got an approach that gets 90% of the way there, but I'm not sure how to finish the deed. To get a single legend for size, I used a transformation to convert input size to display size. That makes the legend appearance conform to the display. What I don't have figured out yet is how to apply a similar transformation to the `fill` so that both can be integrated into the same legend.

Here's the transformation, which in this case shrinks everything 10 or more:

```
library(scales)
shrink_10s_trans = trans_new("shrink_10s",
          transform = function(y){
            yt = if_else(y >= 10, y*0.1, y)
            return(yt)
          },
          inverse = function(yt){
            return(yt) # Not 1-to-1 function, picking one possibility
          }
)
```

Then we can use this transformation on the size to selectively shink only the dots that are 10 or larger. This works out nicely for the legend, aside from integrating the fill encoding with the size encoding.

```
ggplot(xm,aes(x= Samples,y= fct_rev(Species), fill = Size < 10))+
  geom_point(aes(size=Size), shape = 21)+
  scale_size_area(trans = shrink_10s_trans, max_size = 10,
                  breaks = c(1,2,3,10,20,30,40),
                  labels = c(1,2,3,10,20,30,40)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(rgb(136,93,100, maxColorValue = 255),
                               rgb(236,160,172, maxColorValue = 255))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon! At this point it isn't a big problem and I will be able to use Illustrator to add  the color. Not as satisfying, but it's already a lot close to what I am aiming at. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

Species <- factor(c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species5"))

bubba <- data.frame(Sample1 = a, Sample2 = b, Species = Species)
bubba$Species <- factor(bubba$Species, levels = bubba$Species)
xm <- reshape2::melt(bubba, id.vars = "Species", variable.name = "Samples", value.name = "Size")

ggplot(xm, aes(x = Samples, y = fct_rev(Species))) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Size, color = Size)) +
  scale_color_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,10,20,30), guide = guide_legend()) +
  scale_size(range = range(xm$Size), breaks = c(1,2,3,10,20,30)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: But what about when the value (i.e., relative abundance) is not defined exactly by a factor? For example, in the OP's plot there are brown symbols smaller than 10 (but presumably greater than 3 or they'd be a pink symbol).

Comment: It now uses your data. If you want to change the circle sizes or use discrete colors you're going to have to do some wrangling with `guides()` or use factors.

Comment: Thanks! Yes my point for instance in the figure you notice that the break size 3 and break 40 and same size, but different colors. I am struggling on this point. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cludge. I haven't got time to figure out the legend at the moment. Note that 1 and 10 are the same size, but a different colour, as are 3 and 40.

```
# Create data frame
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
Species <- factor(c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species5"))
bubba <- data.frame(Sample1 = a, Sample2 = b, Species = Species)

# Restructure data
xm <- reshape2::melt(bubba, id.vars = "Species", variable.name = "Samples", value.name = "Size")

# Calculate bubble size
bubble_size <- function(val){
  ifelse(val > 3, (1/15) * val + (1/3), val)
}

# Calculate bubble colour
bubble_colour <- function(val){
  ifelse(val > 3, "A", "B")
}

# Calculate bubble size and colour
xm %<>% 
  mutate(bub_size = bubble_size(Size),
         bub_col = bubble_colour(Size))

# Plot data
ggplot(xm, aes(x = Samples, y = fct_rev(Species))) +
  geom_point(aes(size = bub_size, fill = bub_col), shape = 21, colour = "black") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = alpha("gray", 0.5), linetype = "dashed"),
        text = element_text(family = "serif"),
        legend.position = "none") + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 20)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("brown", "pink")) +
  ylab("Species")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Legend wouldn't be a problem, at this point I am sure I would have been able to set it the right size data and use Illustrator to finalize the work (although not completely satisfying, but if it works!). However I encountered the issue where %<>% was function not found. Is there a specific package in addition i should add?

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot to mention: you need the `magrittr` package for the compound assignment operator.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for bubble plots in `R`

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/bubble-chart/

That said, you probably want to build the right and left the side of the graphic separately and then combine.

Comment: Hi jrakru56, yes I know thanks. I have questionning about adding two different scales. As on the picture, there is a range of point size for size value 1 to 3 and another set of points for size range 10 to 40. I am struggling on how to do this.

Comment: Oh I see!  Actually, I was wrong. This is not a bubble plot. It is just a regular plot with a different symbol for the different groups based on some bin size.  You could accomplish the same effect using a combination of point shape and point sizes.

Comment: `df <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "wt")];
df1 <- df %>% filter(wt <4);
df2 <- df %>% filter(wt >=4);


ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(x=wt, y=mpg), shape=21, fill="steelblue", color="darkred", size=3) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x=wt, y=mpg), shape=21, fill="steelblue", color="darkred", size=10)`